# Django creating a user with wrong data freezes shell

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a user model,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, validators=[validate_username, ])

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'user'
        verbose_name_plural = 'users'


    def save(self, **kwargs):
        print "saving object"
        if self.username is not None:
            self.username = validate_username(self.username.lower())
        super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(**kwargs)
```

the validators,

```
def validate_username(value):
    valid_username = r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,15}$'
    validator = RegexValidator(regex=valid_username, message='alphanumerics and underscores are allowed [1-15].',
                               code='Invalid Number')
    validator(value)
    return value
```

this works for every correct input,

While just trying to create a user with invalid data,
    `>>> User.objects.create(username=u"___", email="lorem@example.com")`

Django shell is not even responding after I enter this. What is the wrong thing going on?

Comment: Try to implement a simpler User class(just for debugging), check DB connection

Answer (score 0):

I could replicate the error with PyCharm's Django shell but not with Django shell on terminal. If you are using PyCharm, I guess the issue is with PyCharm's shell.